# FREAD C pointer problem

Tags: c, pointers, fread

Hi i have a really frustrating problem with pointers could somebody let me know what I am doing incorrectly here.
Thanks

```
// This functions reads from the file 
void get__data_block_from_disk(char* ptr, int block_num){
    int file_desc;
    int x;
    open_fs(file_path);
    file_desc = fileno(fileptr);
    x = lseek(file_desc, DATA_BLOCK_OFFSET + block_num*BLOCK_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
    close_fs();
}

// This function writes to the file
void place__data_block_into_disk(char* ptr, int block_num){
    int file_desc;
    int x;
    printf("char in place: %c\n", ptr);
    open_fs(file_path);
    file_desc = fileno(fileptr);
    x = lseek(file_desc, DATA_BLOCK_OFFSET + block_num*BLOCK_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
    close_fs();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have written

```
fread(&ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

where you intended:

```
fread(ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

The reason this is a problem is that `ptr` is supplied to `get__data_block_from_disk` as a `char *`.  Therefore, I assume `ptr` points to memory intended to receive the result.  (I hope you have pointed to *enough* memory, but you haven't provided a listing of the calling code for this case.)

Given that `ptr` is already a pointer to the memory you would like to read file data into, it is that pointer which you provide to `fread`.  By supplying the address of `ptr`, by writing `&ptr`, you are advising `fread()` to overwrite the memory which stores `ptr` and any adjacent variables.  No doubt, this is not what you intended.

If you are making the mistake of compiling your C code with a C++ compiler, please stop.  But in case you are, be aware that the C++ compiler will complain about the lack of a `reinterpret_cast<>` casting `ptr` from `char *` to `void *`.

Comment: Thank you, you explanation makes so much sense.

Comment: Cool.  If this or the other answer got you unstuck, click the check-mark next to the answer which helped.  This marks your question "answered" and gives the recipient 15 points.  :)

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt i tried that but im getting the memories adress instead of its value

Answer (score 3):

You do *not* want to mix lseek and fread.  If you use lseek on the file descriptor, use read on the file descriptor.  If you use fread on the FILE *, use fseek on the FILE *.  Mixing the two will almost certainly not give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
fread(&ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

Should be

```
fread(ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

or instead you change

```
void get__data_block_from_disk(char* ptr, int block_num){
```

to

```
void get__data_block_from_disk(char** ptr, int block_num){
```

and

```
fread(&ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

to

```
fread(*ptr, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, fileptr);
```

Explanation:

Fread first parameter should be a pointer and when you write &ptr you send in the pointers memory adress.

Comment: How would that second change help?  It would make sense if had written `*ptr` instead of `&ptr`, but this is the opposite case.

Comment: I got confused, of course the second one will only work if it's *ptr and not &ptr. Thanks for pointing that out for me :)

Comment: And also given that you run the function like this: get__data_block_from_disk(&ptr, 1);